# Is there any way to configure baseURL in relation to the current domain?

Tags: reactjs, axios, bitbucket, web-deployment

I have deployment environments and difference domains(test-1-site.com, test-2-site.com).

I wish to dynamically set baseURL depending on what environment my application is in.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: URL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
    },
});
```

I tried to do it with bitbucket and variables and get this in process.env, but it doesn't work. Now I'm looking for a way to do it differently. How can this be done without bad code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I ask, what is the main purpose? Do you want to have one base url while you are developing on localhost, and another one when your deploy your application on staging or production?

Comment: Try to remove baseURL then..

Comment: I want to have 2-3 different baseURL in code for deployed apps which are different by domains(each app have their own environment in Staging environments in my bitbucket and deploy to difference domains). I want it to be dynamically in my code

Comment: if the api endpoint is the same as the origin then you could follow my answer below, but if it's not, I think you could use REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT variable when you bundle the app, set the API endpoint to the corresponding environment

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.origin` returns everything before the pathname. So if you open the console (F12) and type it now, you will get 'https://stackoverflow.com'

Comment: I thought about it. Is this the only solution?

Comment: As far as I know. Works when using localhost as well as any other origin. Server and frontend would have to be on same subdomain though.

Answer (score 0):

From axios [doc](https://github.com/axios/axios):

```
  // `baseURL` will be prepended to `url` unless `url` is absolute.
  // It can be convenient to set `baseURL` for an instance of axios to pass relative URLs
  // to methods of that instance.
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
```

So you could just add the prefix for the url or simply just leave it an empty slash:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'api/',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
    },
});
```